# Find Last Occurrence of A Duplicate, Sum All Duplicate Values, and Insert Result Only At The Last Duplicate Occurence's Address

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

In one of the columns, I have duplicate values, I want to find the last occurrence of the duplicate value in that column, and then sum all the values belonging to those duplicates, and insert the result of the sum only at the last occurrence of the duplicate's row/column address.

In the sample image below, column A contains the duplicate values, in the sample the column is sorted but in reality it won't be. Column D contains the values that need to be summed for the duplicates.

The last occurence of the value in A2 appears in A4, so what I require is to sum D2 to D4 and place the result, let's say in a new column that I will create, E4. So the result in E4 will be 18:00:00 only, and other occurrence's will remain blank.

[image]

I can easily achieve this with VBA, but unfortunately I'm trying to automate the sheets using formulas intended to work for Office 2016 where macro-enabled files are also not allowed to be opened/runned due to security policies. My development environment is Excel 365 for Mac. If suggestions based on 365 are also provided, I can look for converting them to work on 2016.

I have tried multiple SUMPRODUCT, SUMIF, COUNTIF, LOOKUP etc to try and circumvent this issue but unable to get the desired result or unable to combine the functions to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the results to be in the column right next to the table and aligned with the last occurence of the duplicate? You could very easily just use a pivot table for a summary that will do pretty much what you are asking for, only arranged differently.

Comment: Unfortunately, pivot table won't auto refresh when new data is added (if I'm not wrong or outdated on the matter). The data will keep being added throughout the day.

Comment: Just so you know, I edited my answer a bunch of times...I replaced semicolons with commas in the formula and changed the formula a little. It should totally work, I tested it. Adding rows to the table with names that are already in there will move the sum to the new row. It does not need to be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this works, it appears to me that it does but I'm not 100% sure. If this does work, it is OK for Excel 2010.

Table called "data", must start from column A

| name | val | fin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 |  |
| b | 1 |  |
| c | 1 | 1 |
| a | 1 |  |
| a | 1 | 3 |
| d | 1 |  |
| d | 1 | 2 |
| b | 1 | 2 |

formula for the "fin" column:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([@name],INDIRECT("A" & (ROW() + 1) & ":A" & (ROWS(data)+ROW(data))),0)),SUMIF([name],[@name],[val]),"")
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It sums up the values correctly, but the result appears in front of each row, rather than the result displayed by you (which is the intended objective to achieve). BTW my test environment is Excel 365 on a MAC if that helps.

Edit: OK, I was making a mistake as I oversaw the ROW(data) where data is referencing the table, replaced with my own table name and now it works!

Comment: @MajorAly What do you mean by "in front of each row" ? As in one row above where it's supposed to be? That's strange, I can't replicate it. I added a screenshot of my table and the formula I'm using. Can you compare it with what you have? Even empty rows above the table shouldn't cause what you are describing.

Comment: I edited my comment to reflect on the mistake I was making. It works as intended. Thank You. I will test out a bit more and will then select your answer as accepted.

Comment: @MajorAly perfect! I edited the formula a bit one last time to make it work properly with empty rows above the table. If you know you will never have those, you can just use the previous version.

Comment: Upvoted, the formula works perfectly

Comment: Good idea using the error to skip the additional elements, will be sure to implement this with other issues!

Comment: @andrewb Thank you for your time and effort to resolve an issue of mine and yes I will be sure to use the updated formula as well because I know there will be empty rows. Selected your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

*I have tried multiple SUMPRODUCT, SUMIF, COUNTIF*

That's exactly what you need **but with dynamic ranges** in the COUNTIF:

[image]

Formula in cell C2 is:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$22,A2)))=0,"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$22,A2,$B$2:$B$22))
```

Please, notice the first COUNTIF used **dynamic** range (it increases size when you drag down formula). Also, I'm using SUMIF, not SUMIFS (but SUMIFS will work too)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I do appreciate you taking the time out to work on this. I have selected @andrewb's answer as the correct/most helpful one.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$29, A2)>1, IF(ISNUMBER(XLOOKUP(A2, A3:$A$29, A3:$A$29)), "",TRUE), TRUE)
```

Pasting the above in E2 will return a TRUE value at every instance of a last occurring value, which could be used to build a SUMIF function.

I hesitate to go further as I'm not too experienced with Office 2016 (I believe XLOOKUP will need replacing), but hopefully you can adapt my answer to work.

Comment: This returns TRUE for all the values, whether unique value or a duplicate, regardless of last occurrence.

Comment: That's odd, it works for me. Did you change it at all - e.g. the XLOOKUP part, or the absolute references?

Comment: Yes, I did. Since I'm also using Excel 365 as my environment for now, tested your code as is, because it doesn't need changing for the test, but it just gives TRUE for all.

Comment: Not sure why that's happening for you sorry, but it looks like the other answer works so I'll leave it

Comment: That's okay no issue, thank you for your time and effort to atleast work on a solution!